# what is the redirect url to be used for OneDrive for business code flow?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, onedrive

We have `developed a windows application to upload/download file on a OneDrive account using LiveSDK`.

As `new requirement now we need to support OneDrive for Business also.`

**Url for access token for LiveSDK :**
[https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id={client_id}&scope=wl.signin%20wl.offline_access%20onedrive.readwrite&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf](https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=%7Bclient_id%7D&scope=wl.signin%20wl.offline_access%20onedrive.readwrite&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf)

**As switching to code flow for using OneDrive for Business we are using**

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=%7Bclient_id%7D&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf)

Can anyone please help with `redirect_uri` to be used here?
Application is been registered in azure portal.Following the steps in this MS blog post

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/aad-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online#register-your-app-with-azure-active-directory]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are talking about should be the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) of Azure AD. Your `redirect_uri` does not seem to be a problem, you only need to add it to the application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I'm using.

```
URI_PERSONAL_ACCOUNT        = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf"

URI_BUSINESS_ACCOUNT    = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/"
```

[image]